# Add row dynamically and pass the value to controller

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

**Scenario :** Initially my form has no rows. When I click add button a new row is created and I enter details in it. If I want another row, I click add button and enter details. When all the details are added, I click submit, which sends all the information to the controller.

**Here is my code :**

RoomOperation.cshtml

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s4">
    Item Name
  </div>
  <div class="col s2">
    Rate
  </div>
  <div class="col s2">
    Qty
  </div>
  <div class="col s2">
    Total
  </div>
  <div class="col s1">
    <a class="btn-floating btn-xs waves-effect waves-light red" onclick="addItems()"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
  </div>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("PostChargesPV","Home"))
{
    <div class="addItem">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("PostChargesPV"); }
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Save Bill</button>
}
...
<script type="text/javascript">
  function addItems() {
    $(".addItem").append($("div.singleItem").html());
  }
</script>
```

PostChargesPV.cshtml

```
@model HMS.Reports.ViewModel.HouseKeeping.RoomPostCharges
<div class="singleItem">
  <div class="col s4">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.itemName)
  </div>
  <div class="col s2">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.rate)
  </div>
  <div class="col s2">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.qty)
  </div>
  <div class="col s2">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.total)
  </div>
  <div class="col s1">
    <a class="btn-floating btn-xs waves-effect waves-light red" onclick="removeItem()"><i class="material-icons">remove</i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

HomeController.cs

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult PostChargesPV(List<RoomPostCharges> pc) 
{ 
  //pc is null
  return PartialView(); 
}
```

I got my desired UI but the data is not passing to the controllers. Any advice would be helpful. Thank you.

If there is any alternate way. Please let me know.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I see to do this is to build your list using javascript and pass it through an ajax call.

```
<div class="addItem">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("PostChargesPV"); }
</div>
<button onclick="submitForm();">Save Bill</button>
```

And then just implement the function to construct your list and pass it to the controller in the `submitForm()` method.